# Extract own ui-component to one place

Tags: html, css, angular

I am learning angular, thus I am not interested in neither `bootstrap` nor `ng-bootstrap` as for learning purposes I want to do everything by myself.

I've created a simple dropdown. My goal is to keep it in one place and use in many different compnents but I would like to avoid code repetition as much as I can.

What I have is:

- Class file

```
    export class DropdownElement {
      private _currentValue: string;
      private _listContent: string[];
      private _unrolled: boolean;

      //constructor with getters/setter ommitted for brevity
    }
```

- Inside a component that uses that dropdown

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-users',
      templateUrl: './users.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
    })
    export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

      private userTypeDropdown: DropdownElement;

      constructor() {
        this.userTypeDropdown = new DropdownElement('Select a type', [
          {
            name: 'Admin'
          },
          {
            name: 'Guest'
          }
        ], false);
      }

      private dropdownClicked(dropdownElement: DropdownElement): void {
        dropdownElement.open = !dropdownElement.open;
      }

      private dropdownEntryClicked(dropdownEntry: string, dropdown: DropdownElement): void {
        dropdown.currentValue = dropdownEntry;
      }

      private closeDropdown(event: Event, dropdown: DropdownElement): void {
        dropdown.open = false;
      }
    }
```

- Inside template file

```
    <div class="dropdown-box" (clickOutside)="closeDropdown($event, userTypeDropdown)">
      <div class="dropdown-btn-box">
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn-with-label"
                (click)="dropdownBtnClicked(userTypeDropdown)">
          {{userTypeDropdown.currentValue}}
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="caret-down-btn" (click)="dropdownClicked(userTypeDropdown)">
          <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <ul class="dropdown-ul" *ngIf="userTypeDropdown.unrolled">
        <li *ngFor="let listEntry of userTypeDropdown.listContent" class="dropdown-list-entry"
            (click)="dropdownEntryClicked(listEntry, userTypeDropdown)">
          {{listEntry.currentValue}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

- `.scss` file left out for brevity

I would like to keep it in one place (to avoid code repetition) and use in different components.

How I would do that.
I believe that's exactly what was done in `ng-bootstrap`. They took dropdown from `bootstrap` wrapped it in some logic making it a directive and that's it. I think the answer here is implemented it either as a directive or as a child component (but not sure if `@Input`/`@Output` is the right choice for that purpose). Again, as I said, I'm a beginner so I might be wrong, thus the question.

What is the right approach here to "keep dropdown definition in one place and use in many places" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module for all these reusable components like dropdown, modal or even HTML input controls which can encapsulate your validations and functionalities over the baseline functionalities that they hold. 
You can further abstract out the framework independent code into further classes and just use Angular for viewing. Just like you abstracted out your code into a Dropdown element class you can have a basic dropdown component that provides the view, which you achieved using your app-users. You can make it more reusable by taking out the dropdown view also in a separate component, doing this will help you in using the dropdown element in all such use cases where you require a dropdown. You just provide the drop down element with initializing data and initial value and you are good to go.

- DropDown Class and the reusable component

  ```
  export class Dropdown {
    private _currentValue: string;
    private _listContent: string[];
    private _unrolled: boolean;

    //constructor with getters/setter ommitted for brevity
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'drop-down',
    templateUrl: './drop-down.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./drop-down.component.scss']
  })
  export class DropDownComponent extends Dropdown implements OnInit {
    // Input are a way to of communication from parent to child as parent feeds the child with input properties
    // you can have your setter here
    @Input('list-content')
    public listContent : Array<any>;
    @Input('current-value')
    currentValue: any;
    // Output events are just a way of child to parent communication
    @Output('on-select-item')
    onSelectItem : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {}

    public dropdownClicked(): void {
      this.open = !this.open;
    }

    public dropdownEntryClicked(dropdownEntry: string): void {
      this.currentValue = dropdownEntry;
      this.onSelectItem.emit(this.currentValue);  
    }

    public closeDropdown(): void {
      this.open = false;
    }
  }
  ```
- App-users using this Dropdown reusable component
  Considering you are a beginner lets keep both of them in the same module so App-users is present in the same module as DropdownComponent. (You can later move the dropdown to a SharedModule and use it by importing the SharedModule in the module containing AppUsersComponent)

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-users',
    templateUrl: './users.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
  })
  export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

   public userTypeDropdown: Array<any>;
   public defaultUserType = { name: 'Guest'};
   public selectedUserType: any;

   constructor() {
       this.userTypeDropdown = ['Select a type',
         {
           name: 'Admin'
         },
         {
           name: 'Guest'
         }
      ];
   }
    public onSelectUser (userTypeSelected : any) : void {
       this.selectedUserType = userTypeSelected;
    }
  }
  ```
- Template for dropdown will be the same you used for app-users with some changes ie function arguments (as I have changed some)
- App-user Component's Template ***MAIN HIGHLIGHT***

```html
<drop-down [list-content]="userTypeDropdown"
[current-value]="defaultUserType"
(on-select-item)="onSelectUser(userTypeSelected)></drop-down>
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: `You can make it more reusable by taking out the dropdown view also in a separate component` so in order to achieve that, I would have to create a seprate component like f.e. `desktop-dropdown-component` that will 1) extend `DropDownComponent` 2) provide a template (f.e. for desktop screen). Then I could create another component like f.e. `mobile-dropdown-component` that will 1) extend `DropDownCompnent` 2) provide a template (f.e. for mobile screen). Is it what you meant ? ('cause I am not sure If I got it right)

Comment: If your use case demands to have entirely 2 different screens for mobile and desktop for a dropdown then yes you can have 2 different components for dropdown but the basic functionality of dropdown still remains reusable as it is present in your Dropdown class and not in your component's .ts file. But I wonder why would have two separate templates when you can have one and make it responsive.

Comment: I am just trying to undetstand what you  meant by `You can make it more reusable by taking out the dropdown view also in a separate component`. So what would be the use-case/advantage for having template not in `DropDownComponent` but in separate component ?

Comment: Right now you had the template for dropdown in ur app-users' template and if u had to use the same drop down u had to create a similar template for another use case. I suggested having a dropdown component with that template you used for appusers so that you can cover all such use cases with just using dropdown selector.

Comment: ok, but if I kept dropdown template in `drop-down.component.html` that would be ok, right ? then I could have it definied once in there and use in many different components (like f.e. in `app-users`) without any repetition, right ?

Comment: last question. I have removed own constructor from `Dropdown` class and in `DropDownComponent` did: `constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    listContent = this.listContent;
    currentValue = this.currentValue;

    this.unrolled = false;
  }` Is it ok ? (because according to the doc I have access to `@Input` data in `ngOnInit()` and not in `constructor`

Comment: ngOnInit () {    listContent = this.listContent; currentValue = this.currentValue; this.unrolled = false;              }  // Here listcontent , currentValue  are local variables ? Why do you need that ? Also, yes the order of initializations work as first : class variables are initialized then constructor is called , then I/O variables initialized and finally ngOnInit. You can refer to LifeCycle Hooks in Component  (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Answer (score 1):

You can insert components in other components using `selector` in your file `component.ts` selector is `app-user` and you can use it in other component.html templates as `<app-users></app-users>`

in a comment you were ask about passing data to component here is example:

child hello.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  template: '<p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>',
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

father hello-list.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let hello of hellos"
 <app-hello [name]='hello'></app-hello>
</div>
```

remember to download an list in a `hello-list.component.ts` file

Comment: so you say that creating a new component (f.e. `own-dropdown.component.ts`) and embedding it on other components (that require dropdown) is the right approach here, am I correct ? Isn't it a problem If I had a component f.e. `users-list.component.ts` that requires `5` dropdowns (thus, `5` child components of `own-dropdown.component.ts`) ? I'm just asking, as I'm not sure If I got it right.

Comment: In this situation if you need list of users create `user.component.ts` where you display one user info and dropdown then create `users-list.component.ts` where you donwload users list and pass it via `*ngFor` to child component of `user.component.ts.`